# Recursive generators in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, generator

## Introduction

Since version 5.5 in PHP there's such great thing as [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php). I will not repeat official manual page, but they are great thing for short definition of iterators. The most-known sample is:

```
function xrange($from, $till, $step)
{
   if ($from>$till || $step<=0)
   {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid range initializers');
   }

   for ($i = $from; $i < $till; $i += $step)
   {
      yield $i;
   }
}

//...

foreach (xrange(2, 13, 3) as $i)
{
   echo($i.PHP_EOL); // 2,5,8,11
}
```

and generator is actually not a function, but an instance of a concrete class:

```
get_class(xrange(1, 10, 1)); // Generator
```

## The problem

Done with RTM stuff, now moving on to my question. Imagine that we want to create generator of [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Normally, to get those, we can use simple function:

```
function fibonacci($n)
{
   if(!is_int($n) || $n<0)
   {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid sequence limit');
   }
   return $n < 2 ? $n : fibonacci($n-1) + fibonacci($n-2);
}

var_dump(fibonacci(6)); // 8
```

Let's transform this into something, that holds *sequence* and not only it's last member:

```
function fibonacci($n)
{
   if (!is_int($n) || $n<0)
   {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid sequence limit');
   }
   if ($n<2)
   {
      return range(0, $n);
   }
   $n1 = fibonacci($n-1);
   $n2 = fibonacci($n-2);
   return array_merge($n1, [array_pop($n1)+array_pop($n2)]);
}

//...

foreach (fibonacci(6) as $i)
{
   echo($i.PHP_EOL); // 0,1,1,2,3,5,8
}
```

We have now a function that returns array with full sequence

## The question

Finally, the question part: how can I transform my latest `fibonacci` function so it will **yield** my values, not holding them in an array? My `$n` can be big, so I want to use benefits of generators, like in `xrange` sample. Pseudo-code will be:

```
function fibonacci($n)
{
   if (!is_int($n) || $n<0)
   {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid sequence limit');
   }

   if ($n<2)
   {
      yield $n;
   }

   yield fibonacci($n-2) + fibonacci($n-1);
}
```

But this, obviously, is crap since we can't handle with it like this way because recursion will cause object of class `Generator` and not `int` value.

*Bonus*: getting fibonacci sequence is just a sample for more general question: how to use generators with recursion in common case? Of course, I can use standard [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) for that or re-write my function to avoid recursion. But I want to achieve that with generators. Is this possible? Does this worth efforts to use this such way?

Comment: When you *call* a generator, what you get back is a... generator object. This object holds *state* and returns and advances that state when asked to. A recursive function OTOH takes a value and returns a value. I don't see how these two are compatible with each other. Awaiting further opinions though.

Comment: @deceze that's my though for now too. I.e. 'No way to do this' is also good answer if it has enough proof.

Comment: I guess you *could* do it with enough introspection and polymorphic behaviour, but why would you want to? I think it's hard to prove that it's *not* possible, but it's easy enough to prove that writing it in a non-recursive fashion is much simpler. (Prove: you have no idea where to even start. ;))

Comment: .. and that is part of question too :p I.e. if 'it does not worth to act this way' - then I glad to see an answer - why. I have no idea for now, yes :/ shame on me. My usual SO questions always have my own solution (even is it's not well)

Comment: I've actually found a valid use case for recursive generators.... will post more details later once I've pushed an example to github this evening

Comment: That would be great (cause my current though was - that they are near useless)

Comment: I find recursive generators useful for iterating over a tree. Here are gists (code examples) how to do it in PHP5.5+ and PHP7.0+ (with `yield from`): 5.5+: https://gist.github.com/petrkotek/90137df6abb20d3030770c8401ec00c7 7.0+: https://gist.github.com/petrkotek/d4cb2350edf181f29c9219613a25c01e

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've finally identified a real-world use for recursive generators.

I've been exploring [QuadTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) datastructures recently. For those not familiar with QuadTrees, they're a tree-based datastructure use for geospatial indexing, and allowing a fast search lookup of all points/locations within a defined bounding box.
Each node in the QuadTree represents a segment of the mapped region, and acts as a bucket in which locations are stored... but a bucket of restricted size. When a bucket overflows, the QuadTree node splits off 4 child nodes, representing the North-west, North-east, South-west and South-east areas of the parent node, and starts to fill those.

When searching for locations falling within a specified bounding box, the search routine starts at the top-level node, testing all the locations in that bucket; then recurses into the child nodes, testing whether they intersect with the bounding box, or are encompassed by the bounding box, testing each QuadTree node within that set, then recursing again down through the tree. Each node may return none, one or many locations.

I implemented a basic [QuadTree](https://github.com/MarkBaker/QuadTrees) in PHP, designed to return an array of results; then realised that it might be a valid use case for a recursive generator, so I implemented a [GeneratorQuadTree](https://github.com/MarkBaker/GeneratorQuadTrees) that can be accessed in a foreach() loop yielding a single result each iteration.

It seems a much more valid use-case for recursive generators because it is a truly recursive search function, and because each generator may return none, one or many results rather than a single result. Effectively, each nested generator is handling a part of the search, feeding its results back up through the tree through its parent.

The code is rather too much to post here; but you can take a look at the implementation on [github](https://github.com/MarkBaker/GeneratorQuadTrees).

It's fractionally slower than the non-generator version (but not significantly): the main benefit is reduction in memory because it isn't simply returning an array of variable size (which can be a significant benefit depending on the number of results returned). The biggest drawback is the fact that the results can't easily be sorted (my non-generator version does a usort() on the results array after it's returned).

Comment: Very interesting. This is even more than I was looking for.

Comment: It was more stumbled upon by chance than design: I'd already written the basic QuadTree code returning an array when somebody I was talking with about generators asked if they had to be functions or could be class methods.... as I didn't have the answer, and had been working on the QuadTrees earlier that day, I decided to try on the search(); and when I saw how it worked I realised that it was recursive as well, and remembered this question.

Comment: I've also emplemented a Trie datastructure in PHP, and that will work the same way with generators; so I'll post a version of that to Github in due course... that has the advantage that it will be automatically sorted by key because of the way the trie is traversed when reading the datastructure

Comment: It definitely isn't easy finding genuine cases where a recursive generator can prove useful; but while Tries or QuadTrees are designed for very specific use cases, traversing any tree structures would probably be an area where recursive generators could have real value.

Answer (score 26):

So the issue I ran into when attempting to create a recursive generator function, is that once you go past your first depth level each subsequent yield is yielding to its parent call rather than the iteration implementation (the loop).

As of php 7 a new feature has been added that allows you to **yield from** a subsequent generator function. This is the new **Generator Delegation** feature: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generator-delegation

This allows us to yield from subsequent recursive calls, which means we can now efficiently write recursive functions with the use of generators.

```
$items = ['what', 'this', 'is', ['is', 'a', ['nested', 'array', ['with', 'a', 'bunch',  ['of', ['values']]]]]];

function processItems($items)
{
    foreach ($items as $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            yield from processItems($value);
            continue;
        }
        yield $value;
    }
}

foreach (processItems($items) as $item)
{
    echo $item . "\n";
}
```

This gives the following output..

```
what
this
is
is
a
nested
array
with
a
bunch
of
values
```

Comment: Yes, aware of that feature. Long live PHP 7, however, on production it won't be possible soon enough. Thanks for the insight, of course

Comment: On PHP5 we can workaround this, see my similar snippet here: https://pastebin.com/00x0DXBG

Answer (score 3):

```
function fibonacci($n)
{
    if($n < 2) {
        yield $n;
    }

    $x = fibonacci($n-1);
    $y = fibonacci($n-2);
    yield $x->current() + $y->current();
}


for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $x = fibonacci($i);
    $value = $x->current();
    echo $i , ' -> ' , $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Hm. That's much better. I.e. we can rely on `current()`, right?

Comment: While this does technically combine recursive functions with generators, it kinda negates the use of generators, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @deceze - simply answering the question of how to use a generator as though it was a simple recursive function :) I make no comment about the appropriateness of doing so

Comment: @deceze yes, I've noticed. With this way I can't do like `foreach(..)` - but that is at least something as a starting point

Comment: @MarkBaker and I will be glad to see your opinion - i.e. if it's bad - then why, e t.c.

Comment: I'm trying to find a valid use that isn't simpler using a straightforward function... if each "nested" generator was being treated as a generator rather than simply as a function, returning a series of results, then perhaps some form of binary search?

Comment: I have been doing some playing around with simulated parallel processing, creating multiple generators and allocating blocks or data for each to work with, then "polling" each in turn for results (sieve of erastophenes) the value of a generator is that it can yield multiple results, so it wins out over functions in that aspect)... so binary searching isn't quite as far-fetched as it might seem

Comment: +1 for the effort, but I can't see any use for something like this either

Comment: I've been thinking about this while I nipped out for a coffee. Possible use: a brute force maze routefinder. Generator is given a map, a start node/point, a direction to travel, and a target node/point; it returns any significant finds it makes - turns, junctions, dead ends (null to terminate) - when it encounters a junction, it takes one direction itself and spawns off other generator(s) to follow the other possible directions. There's certainly better ways to do it though.

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, and that's DFS :)

Answer (score 1):

If you first want to make a generator you might as well use the iterative version of fibonacci:

```
function fibonacci ($from, $to)
{
  $a = 0;
  $b = 1;
  $tmp;
  while( $to > 0 ) {
    if( $from > 0 )
      $from--;
    else
      yield $a;

    $tmp = $a + $b;
    $a=$b;
    $b=$tmp;
    $to--;
  }
}

foreach( fibonacci(10,20) as $fib ) {  
    print "$fib "; // prints "55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 " 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive generator for combinations (order unimportant, without replacement):

```
<?php

function comb($set = [], $size = 0) {
    if ($size == 0) {
        // end of recursion
        yield [];
    }
    // since nothing to yield for an empty set...
    elseif ($set) {
        $prefix = [array_shift($set)];

        foreach (comb($set, $size-1) as $suffix) {
            yield array_merge($prefix, $suffix);
        }

        // same as `yield from comb($set, $size);`
        foreach (comb($set, $size) as $next) {
            yield $next;
        }
    }
}

// let's verify correctness
assert(iterator_to_array(comb([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 3)) == [
    [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4],
    [0, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]
]);

foreach (comb([0, 1, 2, 3], 3) as $combination) {
    echo implode(", ", $combination), "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
0, 1, 2
0, 1, 3
0, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
```

[Same thing non-yielding.](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Recently ran into a problem that needed 'recursive' generators or generator delegation. I ended up writing a little function that converts delegated generators calls into a single generator.

I turned it into a package so you could just require it with composer, or checkout the source here: [hedronium/generator-nest](https://github.com/Hedronium/GeneratorNest).

Code:

```
function nested(Iterator $generator)
{
    $cur = 0;
    $gens = [$generator];

    while ($cur > -1) {
        if ($gens[$cur]->valid()) {
            $key = $gens[$cur]->key();
            $val = $gens[$cur]->current();
            $gens[$cur]->next();
            if ($val instanceof Generator) {
                $gens[] = $val;
                $cur++;
            } else {
                yield $key => $val;
            }
        } else {
            array_pop($gens);
            $cur--;
        }
    }
}
```

You use it like:

```
foreach (nested(recursive_generator()) as $combination) {
    // your code
}
```

Checkout that link above. It has examples.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: recursive generators are simple. Example for walking through tree:

```
class Node {

    public function getChildren() {
        return [ /* array of children */ ];
    }

    public function walk() {
        yield $this;

        foreach ($this->getChildren() as $child) {
            foreach ($child->walk() as $return) {
                yield $return;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

It's all.

Long answer about fibonacci:

Generator is something that is used with `foreach (generator() as $item) { ... }`. But OP wants `fib()` function to return `int`, but at the same time he wants it to return `generator` to be used in `foreach`. It is very confusing.

It is possible to implement recursive generator solution for fibonacci. We just need to put somewere inside `fib()` function a loop that will indeed `yield` each member of the sequence. As generator is supposed to be used with foreach, it looks really wierd, and I do not think it is effective, but here it is:

```
function fibGenerator($n) {
    if ($n < 2) {
        yield $n;
        return;
    }

    // calculating current number
    $x1 = fibGenerator($n - 1);
    $x2 = fibGenerator($n - 2);
    $result = $x1->current() + $x2->current();

    // yielding the sequence
    yield $result;
    yield $x1->current();
    yield $x2->current();

    for ($n = $n - 3; $n >= 0; $n--) {
        $res = fibGenerator($n);
        yield $res->current();
    }
}

foreach (fibGenerator(15) as $x) {
    echo $x . " ";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I am offering two solution for Fibonacci number, with and without recursion:

```
function fib($n)
{
    return ($n < 3) ? ($n == 0) ? 0 : 1 : fib($n - 1) + fib($n - 2);
}
function fib2()
{
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
        echo $a  . "\n";
        $a = $a + $b;
        $b = $a - $b;
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    echo fib($i) . "\n";
}

echo fib2();
```