# XML: why is my DOM traversal function yielding only the top-level node?

Tags: php, xml, recursion, generator

I thought I would write a simple function to visit all the nodes in a DOM tree. I wrote it, gave it a not-too-complex bit of XML to work on, but when I ran it I got only the top-level (DOMDocument) node.

Note that I am using PHP's Generator syntax:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php

Here's my function:

```
function DOMIterate($node)
{
    yield $node;
    if ($node->hasChildNodes())
    {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $subnode) {
            // if($subnode != null) {
                DOMIterate($subnode);
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

And the testcase code that is supposed to print the results:

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($input);

    foreach (DOMIterate($doc) as $node) {
        $type = $node->nodeType;
        if ($type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            $tag = $node-> tagName;
            echo "$tag\n";
        }
        else if ($type == XML_DOCUMENT_NODE) {
            echo "document\n";
        }
        else if ($type == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            $text = $node->wholeText;
            echo "text: $text\n";
        } else {
            $linenum = $node->getLineNo();
            echo "unknown node type: $type at input line $linenum\n";
        }
    }
```

The input XML is the first 18 lines of 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml
plus a closing

Comment: Umm... just thought of something. Is it prohibited for a "generator" function to call itself recursively? If so, does anybody have an example of a "generator" that will traverse a recursive structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP7, you can try this:

```
<?php

$string = <<<EOS
<div level="1">
    <div level="2">
        <p level="3"></p>
        <p level="3"></p>
    </div>
    <div level="2">
        <span level="3"></span>
    </div>
</div>
EOS;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($string);

function DOMIterate($node)
{
    yield $node;
    if ($node->childNodes) {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode) {
            yield from DOMIterate($childNode);
        }
    }
}

foreach (DOMIterate($document) as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeName . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here's a working example - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab4781870f8f988207da78b20093b00ea2e8023b
Keep in mind that you'll also get the text nodes that are contained within the tags.

Comment: The (equivalent) answers from Barmar and motanelu worked when I tried them.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `yield` in a function called from the generator doesn't return the value to the caller of the original generator. You need to use `yield from` to propagate the values back.

```
function DOMIterate($node)
{
    yield $node;
    if ($node->hasChildNodes())
    {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $subnode) {
            // if($subnode != null) {
                yield from DOMIterate($subnode);
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

This requires PHP 7. If you're using an earlier version, see [Recursive generators in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835499/recursive-generators-in-php)